# Angular' Bootstrap drop-down button size

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have some requirements that force me to style angular bootstrap drop-down to be like [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/zmDUjqdtPsql9GJjva4T?p=info):
[image]

Everything works fine except that I need to make the button's text responsive. so what ever user pick in drop-down list should be shown in button.

As you can see I have small triangle on right upper side of drop-down list and when you choose some option with shorter width it will cause problem. like below

[image]

My question i,s is there any way I can fix this issue? for example by setting with of button equal to maxim length I have in drop-down list? or any other solution?

you can find all the code here:

http://plnkr.co/edit/zmDUjqdtPsql9GJjva4T?p=info

```
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').directive('uibDropdownTemplate', ['$log',  function ($log) {
        return {
            restrict: 'EA',
            replace: true,
            scope: {
                defaultText: '@',
                options: '=',             
                selectedOption: '='
            },
            templateUrl: 'drop-down.html', 
            controller: function() {

            },            
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

                if (scope.selectedOption === undefined) {
                    scope.selectedOption = scope.defaultText;
                }

                scope.selectedChange = function(option,$event){ 
                    if(scope.selectedOption === option) {
                        scope.selectedOption = scope.defaultText                        
                        $($event.target).removeClass("option-selected");
                    }               
                    else
                    {
                        scope.selectedOption = option;     
                        $("ul.dropdown-menu>li>a").removeClass("option-selected");
                        $($event.target).addClass("option-selected");

                    }

                };
            }
        };
    }]);
```

Comment: why don't you use a fix width ?

Comment: another solution is to get both width in your directive and  set them with fix width

Comment: @sani I have 2 problems with fix width, 1- I dont know the width since, my drop down is a directive and can be used different time with different options 2- I think I cant set the width for angular bootstrap button

Comment: I saw your plunk , there's one thing to mention , why do you wanna show all text in your select list , why don't you just show this : Are you kidding ...

Comment: @sani that's the requirement :D it's the decision that's been taken by someone else :D

Comment: I guess you've probably already ruled out just moving the carat to the left side?

Comment: @stephen.vakil ya if I couldn't find any solution I am gonna force it to the left

Answer (score 1):

Without fiddling with fonts and `em` and such, I could only come up with a quick-and-dirty solution in terms of setting the width.  The general concept, however, is to determine the max length of your options and then use `ng-class` to manually set the width on your `preCaretText` to the desired width.  It my example, I set it to the max length x 7 px, which seems pretty close on my Chrome browser.

http://plnkr.co/edit/vK3DxLM7mNuKG0w2Q8jv?p=preview

**drop-down.html**

```
            <div class="preCaretText" ng-style="{'width': maxOptionLength * 7+ 'px'} ">{{selectedOption}}</div>
```

**example.js**

```
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').directive('uibDropdownTemplate', ['$log',  function ($log) {
        return {
            restrict: 'EA',
            replace: true,
            scope: {
                defaultText: '@',
                options: '=',             
                selectedOption: '='
            },
            templateUrl: 'drop-down.html', 
            controller: function() {

            },            
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                var maxOptionLength = Math.max.apply(Math, scope.options.map(function (el) { return el.length }));
                scope.maxOptionLength = maxOptionLength;

                if (scope.selectedOption === undefined) {
                    scope.selectedOption = scope.defaultText;
                }

                scope.selectedChange = function(option,$event){ 
                    if(scope.selectedOption === option) {
                        scope.selectedOption = scope.defaultText                        
                        $($event.target).removeClass("option-selected");
                    }               
                    else
                    {
                        scope.selectedOption = option;     
                        $("ul.dropdown-menu>li>a").removeClass("option-selected");
                        $($event.target).addClass("option-selected");

                    }

                };
            }
        };
    }]);
```

Comment: if you change   $scope.items = [
      'aaaa',
      'bbbb',
      'cccc'
  ]; your solution doen't work very well

Comment: That's because bootstrap's css has a minimum width of 160px applied to the dropdown-menu class.  You can get slightly more accurate results by using `ch` units (perhaps 0.85-0.9 x the max width in ch), but if you anticipate the drop down being that small, you may need to override the bootstrap style

Answer (score 0):

Is using a `btn-block` on both your button and dropdown not an option? That way they'll both take the size of their parent element:

```
<div>
    <div class="btn-group btn-block" uib-dropdown >
        <button type="button" class="btn drop btn-block" uib-dropdown-toggle>
            <div class="preCaretDiv">
                <div class="preCaretText">{{selectedOption}} </div>
                <div class="caretCircle">
                    <span class="caret"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </button>
        <ul class="uib-dropdown-menu btn-block" role="menu" aria-labelledby="button-template-url">    
            <li role="menuitem" ng-repeat="option in options" ng-click="selectedChange(option,$event)"><a href="">{{option}}</a></li>           
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/8IiSWese3fVtnG29MmFK?p=preview